# Angular renders / refreshes only when focused

Tags: angularjs

I am an Angular newbie and I am working on some chat website application.

Recently I noticed that when the user receives messages from another contact, and the browser tab is not focused, the message history does not show the new message. Only when i press the tab with the mouse and insert it back to focus it renders the new messages correctly.

Is this behavior by design? if yes, is there a workaround? 
If no and it's a bug, in which direction should i search?

Thanks!

Al

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your message from outside AngularJS (e.g. Socket.io), you need to call `$scope.apply()` so it updates your views.

Or even better, you can define a `saveApply` function that make sure AngularJS is not in `$digest` state which will throw an exception if you call `apply` (hopefully in future releases this will be the default behavior)

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```